# Do we use symfony annotations to decrease conditional statements in our code and make code maintainable?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

In symfony2 Doctrine we use annotations as below:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
```

Do we use it to decrease conditional statements in our code? What is the main purpose of annotations?

I've heard that it decrease overall performance of your site, is that true? Does anyone have experience in the field?

I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Main purpose is convenience - you have all in one place (file) instead of two separate (entity class + yml/xml file with mapping information).

This might be little odd when not used to putting code in comment, but after some time it becomes very natural.

Annotations are after all compiled so in production environment it should have no affection on performance.